# How repeat retrofit request with new post values

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have token to make requests with it, this token have some lifeTime.
So when I get 401 error, I need to refreshToken with other request.
I want to make it smoothly for user(without any interruptions): if get 401, than make refresh, and after it repeat first request with new available token.

here is my code:

```
@POST("/refresh_token")
Observable<Auth> refreshToken(@Body BodyAuth body);

@POST("/someLink")
Observable<Answer> someRequest(@Body OtherBody body);

Observable<Answer> makeSomeRequest(){
    retutn someRequest(new Body(currentToken)).
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .compose(StatusCodeVerifier())
                .retryWhen(RetryWithNewToken(requestManager))
}

public class StatusCodeVerifier<T> implements Observable.Transformer<Response<T>,T> {
    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<Response<T>> responseObservable) {
        return responseObservable.
                flatMap(new Func1<Response<T>, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Response<T> tResponse) {
                        if (tResponse.code() == 401){
                            throw new  UnAuthorizedException("custom exception");
                        } else {
                            return Observable.just(tResponse);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}

public class RetryWithNewToken implements Func1<Observable<Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

    private UserDataManager requestManger;

    public RetryWithNewToken(RequestManager requestManger){
        this.requestManger = requestManger;
    }
    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(final Observable<Throwable> attempts) {
        return attempts.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(final Throwable throwableObservable) {
                if (throwableObservable instanceof UnAuthorizedException){
                    return requestManger. refreshToken().subscribe(new Action1<CbAuth>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(TokenData newToken) {
                            updateToken(newToken);
                            //here i try to repeat previous request that was failed because of 401 error
                            Observable.just(attempts); 
                        }
                    });
                }
                return Observable.error(throwableObservable);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

every time after successful refreshToken previous request called, but it is called with invalid (old one) data.
So how can I repeat request with new token data?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of you initialize your `someRequest` `Observable` with its arguments only once. And when an error occurs you just resubscribes to it. But you have to poll `currentToken` on each subscription. It could be done by using `Observable.fromCallable` operator:

```
Observable<Answer> makeSomeRequest(){
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> currentToken) // called on each subscription
                .flatMap(token -> someRequest(new Body(token)))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .compose(StatusCodeVerifier())
                .retryWhen(RetryWithNewToken(requestManager))
}
```